# spring batch jobexplorer issue

Tags: spring-batch

We are trying to run a spring batch which is failing with below issue.

My configs :

1)  Spring boot

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "some pkgs” })
@ImportResource("classpath:dataSource.xml")
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = DataSourceTransactionManager.class)
public class CollateralReportGeneratorBootstrapper {
public static void main(String[] args) {
     System.exit(SpringApplication.exit(SpringApplication.run(CollateralReportGeneratorBootstrapper.class, args)));
}
```

}

2)  Batch

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "some pkgs”})
public class ReportGenerator {

@Autowired
private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

@Autowired
private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
```

3)  Dependencies  :  spring-batch-core, spring-batch-infrastructure, spring-boot-starter-batch

Please let me know if someone faced this issue or any idea about possible solutions !!

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jobLauncherCommandLineRunner' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/batch/BatchAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 1 of type [org.springframework.batch.core.explore.JobExplorer]: : No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.batch.core.explore.JobExplorer] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.batch.core.explore.JobExplorer] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:747)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:462)
```

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest start with following sample and add your launcher class to it...

http://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/